# operation on files

Tags: php, file, operation

I've got a program which upload a files to a catalog. now i need to build a program which  recognize which files are currently in the directory, based on their content, as well as the $ thefile, $ thefile_name, $ thefile_size, $ thefile_type, display a table of their type in the form of icons, size and name. Also add an option of download, deleting..

Here is my code so far..

first site :

```
<html>
 <body>

 <form action="plikownia.php" method="post"
 enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label for="file">Filename:</label>
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

and a second:

```
<?php
 $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");

 $tmp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

 $extension = end($tmp);
 if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
 || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
 || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
 || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
 && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000000)
 && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
   {
   if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
     {
     echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
     }
   else
     {
     echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
     echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
     echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
     echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

     if (file_exists("C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\upload" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
       {
       echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
       }
     else
       {
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
       "C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\upload" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
       echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
       }
     }
   }
 else
   {
   echo "Invalid file";
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: use `mime_content_type()`

Answer (score 0):

Good solution is to save file info in database. You should save details like id, filename, filesize, path_to_file, extension, mime.

Also it's good to save files on your disk namining them with uniqid() + extension. To get the type of file it's better to use `mime_content_type()` extension can be changed. You can also use `pathinfo()` to get more information about file like extension, basename, filename etc.

Example:

```
<?php
echo mime_content_type('php.gif') . "\n";
echo mime_content_type('test.php');
?>
```

Output:

```
image/gif
text/plain
```

When you use database you can provide link as:

http://yoursite.uk/download.php?file=2 and just select this file from db get it's location and use this part of code:

```
header("Content-type: $mime"); // the mime from your db should be in $mime
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="$pathtofile"'); // $pathtofile from your db
readfile('$pathtofile');
```

Comment: Well i didnt work on databases before :( i need this on my project :) so i have to put files into folder and download them from it ;]

Comment: Panie Adamie :) This is bad solution but you need to list the files for example with DirectoryIterator and you need provide in your link the name of file. To download file you can use the code with "headers" I've provided you in answer.